# How to "select" inside a stored procedure or a UDF in DB2 LUW?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, udf

I believe this question is very trivial. I' unable to select rows inside a stored procedure that I defined, nor inside a UDF. Here is the syntax that I used:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure GenerateSequence(
In InternalUnitID SmallInt,
In ObjectTypeID SmallInt)

Language SQL
Dynamic Result Sets 1
Not Deterministic
No External Action
Modifies SQL Data
Commit On Return Yes
Begin
Select  Number
From    Sequence
Where   InternalUnit=InternalUnitID
    And ObjectType=ObjectTypeID;
End
```

If I try to create the above procedure (by putting the definition in a SQL file and running it). I get the following error message:
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "Select Number  From Sequence  Where Intern" was
found following "n Return Yes Begin  ".  Expected tokens may include: "". 
LINE NUMBER=21.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Any clue what can be the cause of this problem?

My environment is DB2 10.5 Express on Windows.

Comment: Take a look at the manual.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html?pos=2  To return a result set, you simple declare a cursor and open it prior to exiting the procedure.

Comment: number and sequence are both reserved words

Comment: The hardest part of creating a SP for me was always getting the command line options correct for using a different batch terminator from `;` so I can include `;` in my SP code.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0009220.html

Comment: Just another manifestation of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699343/declaring-variable-in-db2-using-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I needed to use a cursor in order to return the result set to the caller of the stored procedure.

References:

[CREATE PROCEDURE (SQL) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html)

[Compound SQL (compiled) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html)